# ¿cómo puedo hacer una base de datos con el año más reciente para cada ciudad a través de un loop?

Tags: r, bucles, rstudio

```
mi_df <- data.frame(
  "ciudades" = c("linares", "parral", "talca","santiago","linares", "parral", "talca","santiago"),
  "anhos" = c(1998,2005,2000,1999,2010,2011,2020,2008),
  "altura.arboles" = c(200,332,120,440,154,222,345,555))`


mi_df$ultima <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(mi_df)){
  for(j in 1:8){
    if((mi_df$anhos[i]>mi_df$anhos[i+1])){
      mi_df$ultima[i]=1}
    else{nada = 0}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En un lenguaje como R en contadas ocasiones sea razonable o práctico usar bucles explícitos (for/while), en tu ejemplo, ciertamente no es necesario usarlo, que más allá de temas de performance, hace más largo de leer e interpretar el código.
Aquí lo que podemos hacer es quedarnos con el año máximo por cada ciudad:

```
ultimos <- aggregate(anhos ~ ciudades, mi_df, max)
ultimos 

  ciudades anhos
1  linares  2010
2   parral  2011
3 santiago  2008
4    talca  2020
```

Con el `aggregate()` agrupamos por `ciudades` y obtenemos el `max()` de cada grupo. Esto nos dá un nuevo `data.frame` que podremos usar para filtrar los datos originales para obtener únicamente las filas que coincidan en `ciudades` y `anhos`

```
merge(mi_df, ultimos, by = c("ciudades", "anhos"))

  ciudades anhos altura.arboles
1  linares  2010            154
2   parral  2011            222
3 santiago  2008            555
4    talca  2020            345
```

Una forma alternativa y altamente recomendable es usar `tidyverse` que permite escribir un código mucho más claro:

```
library(tidyverse)

mi_df %>% 
  group_by(ciudades) %>% 
  filter(anhos==max(anhos))
```

A `mi_df` lo agrupamos por `ciudades` y filtramos en cada grupo la fila cuyos `anhos` sea la máxima de dicho grupo.